# Track certain weekday in Google Analytics

Tags: google-analytics, analytics

I'd like to compare the number of visitors on all Thursdays (of the last 12 month) in a custom report. How can this be done?

Answer (score 1):

Can't be done.

You could try and [compare days of the week across time spans](http://analytics.blogspot.com/2009/07/back-to-basics-comparing-days-of-week.html).

But, with your current information at hand, best you can do is export the analytics to [Google Docs and then run old-fashioned filters](http://www.google.com/support/forum/p/Google+Analytics/thread?tid=49048281d684db46&hl=en) to bring out the results based on what day of the week you want to compare against.